# Can I get the actual fingerprint data from AS608?

Tags: arduino-ide

So I own an AS608 fingerprint scanner, and I've been looking everywhere for information on how to get the fingerprint data (raw, processed, or binary) from the scanner itself to use with a database but to no luck.

I've seen some answers on here, but they don't point to anything specific, so I am bubbling asking again. I have intentions of using this with Atmega MCUs, I just need to get any form of data that I can then tie to a user for a system. Thank you!

This is the [datasheet](https://server4.eca.ir/eshop/000/AS608/Synochip-AS608.pdf), but it doesn't really say if it can do that or not. The datasheet doesn't really talk about its applications.

So this is the fingerprint sensor I have, here is [a link](https://makersportal.com/shop/optical-fingerprint-sensor-as608) to it on a store. It is based on AS608 as RowanP pointed out in the comments.

[image]
[image]

Comment: please provide a link to the manufacturer datasheet for the AS608

Comment: An https://server4.eca.ir/eshop/000/AS608/Synochip-AS608.pdf 144MHz 512KB Cortex-M is capable of many things.  You'd have to find out what the code embedded in the scanner is programmed to communicate.

Comment: https://server4.eca.ir/eshop/000/AS608/Synochip-AS608.pdf

Comment: You’re linking to a microprocessor (AS608) that says it is intended for integration with fingerprint equipment. However after a quick skim of the datasheet it does not seem to have inbuilt fingerprint scanning peripherals. Are you saying it does (if so can you point to the relevant section of the datasheet)? Alternatively are you saying you have it connected to a fingerprint scanner? If so please provide details of the scanner. Or if both of these alternatives are wrong can you provide more information?

Comment: As background (and acknowledging the OP question is more specific) there is a general discussion on this topic here https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/85270/71575

Comment: I did some googling and I can see a number of sensors labelled AS608, which is I guess a reference to the embedded chip. What you might do with the module (eg access to internal data) would depend on how much control you have over the code loaded into the AS608 I would guess. Although these all look the same I’d anticipate a fair bit of variation?

Comment: The best doco I can find is at Adafruit https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-optical-fingerprint-sensor.pdf

Comment: The Adafruit guide @RowanP posted shows it is possible to get images. // 
 https://makersportal.com/shop/optical-fingerprint-sensor-as608 has a pic of their AS608 fingerprint sensor board clearly showing the Synochip AS608 processor on a board silkscreened with "DY50-2V1"  Searching for DY50 leads to Ziantec Fingerprint Module or ZFM Fingerprint module with an english datasheet at https://www.velleman.eu/downloads/29/infosheets/vma329_datasheet.pdf and a chinese one at https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/DY001fingerprint.pdf //  What module do you have? Post pics?

Comment: https://github.com/bastianraschke/pyfingerprint/blob/Development/src/files/examples/example_downloadimage.py is a python example from https://github.com/bastianraschke/pyfingerprint for use with ZhianTec ZFM-20, ZFM-60, ZFM-70 and ZFM-100 and several other modules.  It suggests that the Adafruit Library https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Fingerprint-Sensor-Library is the inspiration.  So yes, it seems possible, but the exact interfacing depends on the module, and what you want to do with it. Do you want to do image processing on the ATMega, or pass it through to a computer? Try the python.

Comment: I want to collect the data and store it on a database and use it for authentication elsewhere. I'm using the AtMega238.

Comment: If you can extract the actual fingerprint data you want from your device with a computer and those python programs, then your device can do it.  If so, then you can look at the python code and maybe adapt/use it or the Adafruit library to accomplish your purpose.  From your Q its hard to tell exactly what device you have or exactly what it is capable of.

Comment: @BeulahAkindele Can you show a photo of the PCB at the back of the actual sensor?

Comment: The thing is... I am using Cpp on an Atmega microcontroller. I really need to consolidate on an MCU solution right now for the project at hand. The python libraries you listed actually use USB fingerprint scanners, I need a serial/GPIO solution.
Also, @RowanP I added the images.

Comment: @DaveX The python libraries you listed actually use USB fingerprint scanners, I need a serial/GPIO solution

Comment: The specific device you actually have is still a bit unclear from your Q.  If it is compatible with the datasheet from Adafruit that you linked, then it looks like yes, you can get the image data out.  They demo that use-case with a (DY20 device) 
 serial/GPIO passthrough to USB rigged on an arduino, and then show the image in a windows app.  If that adafruit library demo works with your device, then the "FINGERPRINT_UPLOAD" Command, 0x08, or "Section 6.3.9 -- Upload Image" in https://www.velleman.eu/downloads/29/infosheets/vma329_datasheet.pdf should get your image.